# request_standard_resources() function in linux arm

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am reading the Linux kernel (2.6.31) source code to learn about memory mapping.

My question is with this function in `/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c`:

```
static void __init request_standard_resources(struct meminfo *mi, struct machine_desc    *mdesc)
{
struct resource *res;
int i;

kernel_code.start   = virt_to_phys(_text);
kernel_code.end     = virt_to_phys(_etext - 1);
kernel_data.start   = virt_to_phys(_data);
kernel_data.end     = virt_to_phys(_end - 1);

for (i = 0; i < mi->nr_banks; i++) {
    if (mi->bank[i].size == 0)
        continue;

    res = alloc_bootmem_low(sizeof(*res));
    res->name  = "System RAM";
    res->start = mi->bank[i].start;
    res->end   = mi->bank[i].start + mi->bank[i].size - 1;
    res->flags = IORESOURCE_MEM | IORESOURCE_BUSY;

    request_resource(&iomem_resource, res);

    if (kernel_code.start >= res->start &&
        kernel_code.end <= res->end)
        request_resource(res, &kernel_code);
    if (kernel_data.start >= res->start &&
        kernel_data.end <= res->end)
        request_resource(res, &kernel_data);
}

if (mdesc->video_start) {
    video_ram.start = mdesc->video_start;
    video_ram.end   = mdesc->video_end;
    request_resource(&iomem_resource, &video_ram);
}

/*
 * Some machines don't have the possibility of ever
 * possessing lp0, lp1 or lp2
 */
if (mdesc->reserve_lp0)
    request_resource(&ioport_resource, &lp0);
if (mdesc->reserve_lp1)
    request_resource(&ioport_resource, &lp1);
if (mdesc->reserve_lp2)
    request_resource(&ioport_resource, &lp2);
}
```

I don't know the value of variables as: _text, _etext, _data, _end.

Please help me to get the value of these variables and the purpose of this function : request_standard_resources()

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are actually defined by the linker script that puts together the final kernel image.

- `_text` is the address of the beginning of the kernel text (code) section.
- `_etext` is the end of the text section.
- `_data` is the beginning of the data section.
- `_end` is the end of the kernel.

Comment: Could you tell me the name of script and the folder contains it?